# How to block wordpress admin by htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

I was trying to block the access from public to my /wp-admin. I can achieve it by doing the following htaccess but the problem is I need to add an exception for sub-url which is /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Comment: Although you are using WordPress, this is purely an Apache/htaccess question really and you'll probably get a quicker answer asking it over on [so]

Comment: haha thanks I posted in stackoverflow first. But even he I got a comment from you but no replies from there yet